# What's the point of deploying spring boot application on an application server like Wildfly?

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly

In my previous company we were using spring boot for our backend and they used to deploy the application on a Wildfly server which i found it weird because spring boot comes with an embedded server that eleminates the need of an application server. I would like to know the point behind this?

Comment: Why didn't you ask your previous company while you were there? They would know best why they chose to do things that way, wouldn't they?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one single big server, running the default fat Wildfly, the waste of resources (DISK/CPU/RAM) is negligible.

Faster deployments, if you are deploying only the app, the update is faster, it doesn't need to restart the entire server stack, so you get 1 or 2 seconds less downtime.