# what are the benefits of deploying a spring boot application on an application server?

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly, application-server

Spring boot comes with an embedded server that facilitates deployment. But based on my experience many companies are still using application servers to deploy their spring boot applications ( WildFly as an example) . I would like to know the advantages of this approach or maybe the use cases where you really need to exclude tomcat from spring boot before deploying it?

Comment: Don't ask the same question each day -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78232120/whats-the-point-of-deploying-spring-boot-application-on-an-application-server-l!